# Is it possible to use a delegate in Groovy which is not a script

Tags: java, groovy

I know that it is possible to use a script as a delegate in Groovy as in (this is the example for the DelegatingScript javadoc in the groovy API):

```
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.setScriptBaseClass(DelegatingScript.class.getName());
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(cl,new Binding(),cc);
DelegatingScript script = (DelegatingScript)sh.parse(new File("my.dsl"))
script.setDelegate(new MyDSL());
script.run();
```

What i want to do is use a Java class extending `DelegatingScript` to delegate method calls rather than using another script. Is it possible?

Currently my code is the following without using delegation:

```
CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
GroovyClassLoader groovyLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClassLoader(), config);
Class<?> groovyClass = groovyLoader.parseClass(scriptContent);
GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
// call methods in GroovyObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use MyDSL class as a base script class

```
abstract class MyDSL extends Script{
    ...
}

CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.setScriptBaseClass(MyDSL.class.getName());
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(cl,new Binding(),cc);
MyDSL script = (MyDSL)sh.parse(new File("my.dsl"))
script.run();
```

Comment: I did not think about that, I will have to try this! Thanks!: